# Connecting opposite nodes

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I have two line graphs of equal length and parallel to each other in networkx, how can i loop over the graphs and connect opposite nodes with two edges ie connect 2 & 2a, 3 & 3a etc

```
nodes1 = [2,5,7,8,9,10]

nodes2 = ['2a','5a','7a','8a','9a','10a']
```

I tried

```
for k in range (0, len(nodes1)):
    for i in range (0, len(nodes2)):
        if nodes1.index(kk) == nodes2.index(i):
            X.add_edge(k,i)
```

But it dosent give the desired output please can anyone correct me. Thanks

```
               This is what I have 
          2---------3---------4----------5----------6



          2a---------3a-------4a--------5a---------6a


                 This is what I want 
            2---------3---------4----------5-----------6
            ||        ||        ||         ||         ||
            ||        ||        ||         ||         ||
            ||        ||        ||         ||         ||
           2a--------3a---------4a---------5a---------6a
```

Sorry if the previous post was not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does not work as is, is because index returns the index in the list where the value resides, so you are looping from `0` to the length of each list and the first value `0` does not exist in your list which throws a `ValueError`. See the online docs: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

If you just wanted to create the tuple pairs and assuming lengths and ordering were already correct then if you modify your code with this line:

```
for k in range (0, len(nodes1)):
    X.add_edge(nodes1[k],nodes2[k])
```

would achieve what you want as you want to traverse both lists in parallel, your original code even if `index` didn't raise a `ValueError` would have resulted in `5 x 5` entries as you were adding an edge for every entry in `nodes2` for each node in `node1` which is not what you wanted.

Assuming your ordering matches for both lists then you can do a list comprehension to create the edge list and create your graph from this

```
In [171]:

edge_list = [(nodes1[i], nodes2[i]) for i in range(len(nodes1))]
# I'm using python 3 so you could do the following also
# edge_list = list(zip(nodes1, nodes2))
G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
G.edges()
Out[171]:
[(2, '2a'), (5, '5a'), (7, '7a'), (8, '8a'), (9, '9a'), (10, '10a')]
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add edges in both directions then you just create a secondary edge_list like so by swapping the order of the lists around:

```
In [194]:

edge_list_reversed = list(zip(nodes2, nodes1))
edge_list_reversed
G.add_edges_from(edge_list_reversed)
G.edges()
Out[194]:
[(2, '2a'),
 (5, '5a'),
 (7, '7a'),
 (8, '8a'),
 (9, '9a'),
 (10, '10a'),
 ('2a', 2),
 ('8a', 8),
 ('9a', 9),
 ('5a', 5),
 ('10a', 10),
 ('7a', 7)]
```

Comment: @Ed thanks the code snippet works and your thoughtful comments.  please how will I go about adding double edges between those nodes. thanks

Comment: @Nobi is your graph a digraph? or an ordingary graph? I will update my answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Use [zip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) method

```
>>>> zip(nodes1, nodes2)
[(2, '2a'), (5, '5a'), (7, '7a'), (8, '8a'), (9, '9a'), (10, '10a')]
```